# Класс Closure в PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Так как анонимные функции используют объекты класса `Closure`, соответственно у меня возник вопрос, как и для чего можно использовать эти объекты в частности методы этого объекта

- *_​_​construct*
- *bind*
- *bindTo*
- *call*

Мануал читал, но смысловую нагрузку не понял, а хотелось бы выяснить что и к чему.

**Дополнение**

```
1. bind(Closure $closure, object $newthis [,mixed $newscope = "static"])
2. bindTo(object $newthis [,mixed $newscope = "static"])
3. call(object $newthis [,mixed $... ])
```

У статического метода 3 аргумента, а у динамического 2, тут мне кажется все понятно т.к отсутствие 3-его аргумента в динамическом методе обусловлено тем что объект `Closure` используется когда мы используем метод `bindTo` в контексте объекта

**Пример 1:**

```
class A
{
    private $value = 100;
}
$a = new A;
$closure = function(){echo $this->value;};
$binding = $closure->bindTo($a,"A"); 

///Если я не напишу "A" то интерпретатор
///выдаст ошибку, как работает второй аргумент, какая область видимости
///имеется ввиду когда я туда ничего не пишу
///(если ничего не указывать туда пропишется значение static, что подразумевается под этим значением)
/// и что вообще возможно туда написать?

///Еще можно передать вместо объекта Null но у меня не получилось, как 
///возможно это сделать?

$binding(); /// Выдаст: 100
```

**Пример 2:**

```
class A
{
    private $value = 100;
}
$a = new A;
$closure = function($arg1, $arg2){echo $this->value + $arg1 + $arg2;};
$closure->call($a, 50, 15); /// Выдаст 165
```

**Вывод:**
Различий между `bindTo` и `сall` не много, ну я не вижу разницы, разве что `call` короче записывается, ну а смысл? Зачем тогда `bindTo`?

Comment: пример использования https://habrahabr.ru/post/186718/

Comment: почитал, обход приватных свойств объекта класса, но это я видел и в мануале =)

Answer (score 6):

1. Конструктор у него приватный. Так что о нем можете забыть и не вспоминать.
2. call - позволяет замыканию запуститься в определенной области видимости. Применений масса.Например, вы получаете от сервера JSON, содержащий массив географических точек, который десериализуется в такой класс:

   ```
   class Point{
       private $lat;
       private $lon;
       private $description;
       private $type;
   }
   ```

   Все бы хорошо, но для дальнейшей обработки вам не нужны отдельные `$lat` и `$lon` в `Point`, а нужно свойство `$coord`, класса `Coordinates`, которое будет их содержать и при этом обладать кучей полезных методов (например выдать расстояние от другой точки, определение страны и т.д. и т.п.). Тогда мы делаем так.

   ```
   $points = массив десериализованных объектов Point;
   $closure = function() { $this->coord = new Coord($this->lat, $this->lon);};
   foreach ($points as $point){
       $closure->call($point);
   }
   ```
3. bindTo, позволяет получить новое замыкание, с переопределенной областью видимости. (bind - то-же, но статически). Применение примерно такое-же как и у call, но дает возможность отложить выполнение и оперировать набором объектов.

Отличие call() от bindTo() в том, что call() выполняет анонимную функцию сразу, а bindTo() только привязывает область видимости. Также, для `call()` автоматически будет выставлена область видимости класса объекта, а для `bind()` и `bindTo()` нет.

Разница bind() и bindTo() в том, что bindTo() - это метод инстанцированного класса Closure, а bind() - статический его метод.

```
<?php
class Foo{
    public $a = "a";
    protected $b = "b";
    private $c = "c";
}

$obj= new Foo();

$cl = function(){echo $this->a, $this->b, $this->c, "\n";};

// выполнится сразу
$cl->call($obj); 

// создаст новый объект Closure, привяжет его к объекту $obj и 
// выставит область видимости private и protected класс Foo
$cl1 = $cl->bindTo($obj, "Foo");     

// то-же самое, но статически
$cl2 = Closure::bind($cl, $obj, "Foo");

// создаст новый Closure, привяжет к нему public объекта $obj, 
// private и protected же останутся текущими
$cl3 = $cl->bindTo($obj);

$cl1();
$cl2();
$cl3();

abc      - $cl->call();
abc      - $cl1();
abc      - $cl2();
a<br />  - $cl3(); Обратите внимание, что public вывелся, а private и protected нет
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property Foo::$b in [...][...]:10
Stack trace:
#0 [...][...](20): Closure-&gt;{closure}()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

Совсем простыми словами.

```
bindTo(object $newthis [,mixed $newscope = "static"])
```

$newthis - определяет, какой объект будет использоваться при использовании слова $this.
$newscope - это область видимости. Она определяет, объекты какого класса, имеющие область видимости `private` и `protected` будут доступны в замыкании.

Для простоты просто представьте себе(см. пример выше), что в замыкании везде вместо $this подставили $obj. Именно за это отвечает первый аргумент.

Со вторым сложнее. Он указывает замыканию, в контексте какого класса это замыкание выполняется. Если он не задан, то замыкание "думает", что оно выполняется ровно в той области видимости, где запущено. Естественно, что при этом, `private` и `protected` поля и методы объекта $obj ему будут недоступны.

Если же вторым параметром указать имя класса (Foo), то замыкание будет думать, что работает внутри класса Foo, то-есть является его методом. В этом случае ему будут доступны и `private` и `protected`.

Я уж и не знаю, как проще объяснить.

PS Инстанцировать класс - это значит создать его экземпляр. Например через оператор `new`.

Comment: Так как я еще сам пытался разобраться что к чему, я понял следующее: Конструктор нужен для того чтобы не плодить объекты через оператор `new`. `bind` - статический метод и вызывается статически. `bindTo` - динамический метод вызывается через контекст объекта класса `Closure`. `call` - остался для меня непонятен т.к он схож c `bind` и `bindTo`. P.S Хотелось бы побольше явных примеров, а не просто описание для чего эти методы нужны

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: @MaximPro дополнил ответ

Comment: А в моем примере где я спрашиваю что такое static и что за эта область видимости будет?

Comment: Из вашего примера `$cl1 = $cl->bindTo($obj,"static");` какая эта область видимости?

Comment: @MaximPro дополнил

Comment: Я попросил объяснить про область видимости, а не показать примеры для разных методов класса `Closure`. Вы написали: `это метод инстанцированного класса Closure` - что значит `инстанцированного`?
В примере вы писали: `выставит область видимости private и protected класс Foo` - что это значит? Мне не понятно, можете писать так чтобы было все понятно?
p.s Я не занудный, просто хочу понять...но когда пишут так что не понимаешь приходится писать еще вопросы

Comment: @MaximPro добавил. Не, если честно, уже утомило. Чтобы было понятно - надо хотя бы терминами владеть.

Comment: Я достаточно неплохо владею терминами, но давайте не будем писать русскими буквами английские слова, а то это уже бред получается. Экземпляр класса (англ. instance)

Comment: Вот то что вы добавили уже лучше! Так всегда бы отвечали, люблю когда материал разбирают "по косточкам". Если взялись объяснять, то держитесь до конца. То есть выходит если второй аргумент мы не указываем это означает что мы остаемся в той области где программа выполняется, в нашем случае это глобальная область видимости. То есть этот static как-нибудь связан c LSB?