# Зачем использовать в классе статические анонимные функции?

Tags: php

Из [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous-functions.static):

> Анонимные функции могут быть объявлены статически. Это предотвратит их
> автоматическое связывание с текущим классом. Объекты также не будут с
> ними связаны во время выполнения.

```
<?php

class Foo {
    function __construct() {
        $func = static function() {
            var_dump($this);
        };

        $func();
    }
};

new Foo();

?>

// Результат выполнения данного примера:
Notice: Undefined variable: this in %s on line %d
NULL
```

Я не понимаю, что такого плохого, если функция будет как-то связана с классом? Если не нужно использовать переменные класса - ну не используй их. Или это просто слово, которое даст понимание расработчикам, что тут не происходит работа с классом и не нужно? Какие есть сценарии в боевом проекте, где это было бы жизненно необходимо, а отсутствие `static` ломало всё напрочь? Есть ли такие примеры?

**p.s.** это не является дубликатом вопроса [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573017/440444б](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573017/440444%D0%B1) потому что там всего много, намешано, да и в целом нет ответа на мои вопросы

Comment: зачем тут метка static-content?

Comment: @PavelMayorov показалось, что там conteXt)

Comment: ничего "плохого" в этом нет, по сути ограничивает область видимости, можно использовать одинаковые имена переменных, внутри и извне функции, а связаны они между собой не будут.

Comment: @Jean-Claude А можно не нагромождать и соблюдать KISS))